# Creating a restful resource using Jersey, is this what I really need?

Tags: web-services, udp, jersey

I am creating a Chrome extension which will send the URL of every page I visit to a remote database to be stored. I am thinking of creating a RESTful service using Jersey (java) but I am wondering if this will have any additional overhead in terms of the generating an unused response.

I am imagining that I will not require any sort of response back from the server after sending the URL (Kind of reminds me of UDP in a sense). Is a RESTful service what I want? (Since the server will not be sending any sort of data back to the user's browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can use a Jersey web service endpoint, but you could also use a simple servlet.  I don't think Jersey is going to add much of an overhead to your incoming requests, but probably not much benefit either. 
Since what you are building is a simple "log this" function and performance is a concern, it sounds like a simple servlet/JSP is likely to meet the need with no risk of unexpected overheads.